# How to SELECT LIKE with wildcard % with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following PHP code to run a MySQL query:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE first_row = :first_row AND second_row LIKE "%:second_row%"');
$stmt->execute(array(':first_row' => "foo", ':second_row' => "bar"));
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid
> parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of
> tokens in /home/kd37875/public_html/my_file.php:5

Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * 
                       FROM my_table 
                       WHERE first_row = :first_row AND 
                             second_row LIKE :second_row');
$stmt->execute([':first_row'  => 'foo', 
                ':second_row' => '%bar%']);
```

So the `%` are simply part of the string, as they have always been.

Comment: sir i have one question from where i learn mysqli, PDO, parameterized,prepared syntax style coding in php??

Comment: @KUMAR Have a look at https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli and https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @KUMAR also look at W3schools it is a wonderful place to start ....

Comment: @Yunfei Chen  okay ..